# How do I model this dependency relationship in Go?

Tags: go, dependency-injection, go-gorm

Consider the following code.

```
import "speaker"

type Cat struct {
  Name string `gorm:"primary_key"`
}

func (c Cat) meow() {
  speaker.NewFelineVoice().Say("meow", c.Name)
}
```

How do I properly mock out the `NewFelineVoice` dependency in this relationship?

I have considered:

```
import "speaker"

type Cat struct {
  Name string `gorm:"primary_key"`
  Voice speaker.FelineVoice `gorm:"-"`
}

func NewCat(name string, voice speaker.FelineVoice) Cat {
  return Cat{Name: name, Voice: voice}
}

func (c Cat) meow() {
  c.Voice.Say("meow", c.Name)
}
```

However, when `gorm` instantiates this `struct` when loading it from the DB, `Voice` will be set to `nil`. In addition, `Cat` is exported (which is required in my case) so it's possible to avoid using the `NewCat` constructor to set `Voice` to a valid value which could introduce bugs.

Is there an idiomatic means of dealing with this case? Can I instruct `gorm` to inject this dependency and deal with the fact someone can instantiate `Cat` with a `nil` `Voice` or should I model this relationship differently?

Comment: What's the relation between `speaker.FelineVoice` and `gorm` (or the database part of your app in general) ? wouldn't a package level global `var voice speaker.Voice`, or perhaps a `var newFelineVoice = func() speaker.Voice` work in your case ?

Comment: I would like to mock out `voice` when testing from another package. I would prefer not to create a global variable to hold a handle to this interface for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Do you have some pattern in mind (perhaps from another language) to mock this kind of function call ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are replacing the call to a global `speaker.NewFelineVoic()` constructor with an extra field in a struct which happens to be processed by your orm.

Try to just find a way to change the way to call this constructor, for example :

```
var mockNewFelineVoice func() speaker.Voice

func newFelineVoice() speaker.Voice {
    if mockNewFelineVoice != nil {
        return mockNewFelineVoice()
    }

    return speaker.NewFelineVoice()
}


type Cat struct { ... }

func (c Cat) meow() {
    newFelineVoice().Say("meow", c.Name)
}
```

Comment: I am trying to mock out `newFelineVoice()` from another package. It doesn't seem like great practice to me to export function to be used for mocking. But, perhaps this is idiomatic in go?